# Python Flask-called process cannot return

Tags: python, flask

A process which I am calling from flask has an issue when using a return statement.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('MREPlus Web API') # Previously __name__; does not work

@app.route('/v1/do/<study>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def do_flask(study):
    process('')

def process(input=''):
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5555')
```

SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

On one of my systems, the function 'process' works fine and returns various outputs depending on conditions. On another, it is still called but does not appear to be interpreted as a function.

Many thanks for suggestions.

Comment: May be a problem with indentation? Did you have a space lesser in one of the system. Your code itself looks fine, you may need to provide more information to figure out the problem

Comment: Updated with minimal complete code. Don't think it is an indentation issue - the code runs fine, just does not allow returns.

Comment: I should mention I am experiencing this in Pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have provided above, when you run the code and go to the specified directory, you end up with a TypeError that says "The function either returned None or ended without a return statement". This means that Flask does not know what to return to the user, so it returns nothing. in order to fix this issue, all you need to do is add the return statement right next to your function call in this line: `process('')`

Your final code should look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash, abort

app = Flask('MREPlus Web API') # Previously __name__; does not work

@app.route('/v1/do/<study>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def do_flask(study):
    return process('') #Add return here

def process(input=''):
    return "asdf"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5555', debug = True)#Add debug = True to restart Flask apps Faster
```